# In Tableau, how to show a dimension as a pattern (not a gradient) in a treemap that already has another dimension on color?

Tags: gradient, tableau-api, dimensions

I have a simple treemap in Tableau that has one dimension already being shown on color.  I would like to add a second dimension that shows as the pattern (not a gradient). For example, a pattern of stripes through the treemap box where that dimension is present. Is this possible?

Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No patterns, but you can have a second dimension shown as shade of the existing color by putting two dimensions on the color shelf. Hold down the shift key when adding the second dimension to the color shelf to avoid replacing the first dimension.